# SharePoint 2013 InfoPath External Connections with Kerberos

Tags: infopath, kerberos, claims, external-data

Environment

- 2 App
- 2 WFE
- 1 DB

C2WTS account- domain\AppPool (Log on as service/act as OS/Impersonate auth policy on all 4 servers)

IIS Kernel mode - off

Delegation for the all four servers:

[image]

Using UDC Connection (also tried without):

```
<udc:Authentication><udc:SSO AppId='InfoPathUDC' CredentialType='Kerberos' /></udc:Authentication>
```

***SPN for domain\appool***

HTTP/sharepoint

HTTP/sharepoint.domain.com

I'm trying to get external data to query correctly inside InfoPath forms as a data connection with Kerberos (to bypass the doublehop), which is a web service from another server. I haven't had this working, however it was working correctly in 2007 (due to classic mode). Not sure what the deal is here, but I keep getting unauthorized (401) or , and I'm assuming it's due to the claims token. Any ideas?

Comment: or do I **need** constrained delegation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the only way to make this work in SharePoint 2013 with Claims Auth is through the Secure Store Service. InfoPath Services does **NOT** use the Claims to Windows Token Service. You need to tie the infopath data connection to a UDCX, and have the authentication point to the SecureStore Service Target Application ID that will then authenticate to the web service in the InfoPath.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandru/archive/2013/02/26/using-web-services-in-infopath-forms-in-sp15.aspx